# How to add two variables in MIPS using addu?

Tags: mips

I am trying to convert the following python code into an equivalent MIPS code.

```
X = int (input())
Y = int(input())
Print(X + Y)
```

Following is the MIPS code I wrote.

```
.text
li $v0,5
syscall
sw $v0,x
li $v0,5
syscall
sw $v0,y
addu $a0,x,y
li $v0,1
syscall

.data
x: .space 4
y: .space 4
```

When I assemble this code I am getting the following error for "addu $a0,x,y" line.

> ERROR: "x": operand is of incorrect type

I am using MARS 4.5 Software to write these codes.
Can someone please show me my mistake and tell me how to do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- Variables represent memory locations, therefore, the MIPS processor
  can only use them in load and store instructions.
- The addu instruction performs addition on the content of two
  **Registers** and store the result in the destination register.

In the above code of mine x and y represent memory locations. Therefore, the error is, with addu instruction, I can't pass x and y as they are not registers (but memory locations). That's why I got **"x": operand is of incorrect type** error. So what I have to do is first store the content of x and y memory locations in two registers and then add them together using addu instruction.

The corrected code is as follows.

```
.text
li $v0,5
syscall
sw $v0,x
li $v0,5
syscall
sw $v0,y
lw $t1,x
lw $t2,y
addu $a0,$t1,$t2
li $v0,1
syscall

.data
x: .space 4
y: .space 4
```